# How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I want to execute my web app as `http://localhost`.

Comment: This might help you http://www.digizol.com/2008/06/tomcat-how-to-change-port-8080.html

Answer (score 218, accepted):

1) Go to `conf` folder in tomcat installation directory

```
 e.g. C:\Tomcat 6.0\conf\
```

2) Edit following tag in `server.xml` *file*

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

3) Change the `port=8080` value to `port=80`

4) Save file.

5) Stop your Tomcat and restart it.

Comment: Also, make sure to stop and restart Tomcat. Just saying. :)

Comment: I did this and I get a 404 error! Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: In `etc/default/tomcat7` set `AUTHBIND=yes`, to avoid a PermissionDenied error for the port 80.

Comment: See Rose's answer for Linux environment !

Comment: This answer lacks the /etc/authbind information, see answer from Rose below

Comment: URL rewriting for outbound rules 'll resolve it. If you change tomcat port to 80 then other websites on iis may get affected.

Answer (score 121):

**Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, in Amazon EC2.**
The following steps resolved this issue for me:

1.
Edit server.xml and change port="8080" to "80"

```
sudo vi /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml

<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

2.
Edit tomcat7 file (if the file is not created then you need to create it)

```
sudo vi /etc/default/tomcat7
```

uncomment and change #AUTHBIND=no to yes

3.
Install authbind

```
sudo apt-get install authbind
```

4.
Run the following commands to provide tomcat7 read+execute on port 80.

```
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown tomcat7 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

5.
Restart tomcat:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart
```

Comment: That one works. Linux people, at least works for me with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Autobind is the correct answer. But note that you can skip autobind in case you are using 'sudo startup.sh' since port 80 will be granted to escalated user.

Comment: Thanks!! I knew about enabling authbind in server config  but didn't know I had to create a file in authbind for registered port! I wish OP had changed the accepted solution to this answer! (I see that you were almost 3 years late in answering :P)

Comment: It works with Tomcat 9 on Lubuntu 18.0.4, without installing `authbind`, only adding the setting.

Comment: this link works for tomcat 9 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65046121

Answer (score 108):

On a Linux Debian-based (so Ubuntu included) you have also to go to `/etc/default/tomcat7`, uncomment the `#AUTHBIND=no` line and set its value to 'yes', in order to let the server bind on a privileged port.

Comment: Hi i dont have that particular file

Comment: What version of tomcat? What OS are you on?

Comment: I also had the issue that the file didn't exist. I started a new machine with reinstall and it appeared...

Comment: Doesn't work for Tomcat if installed by zip/tar.gz, as they don't create the file in /etc/defaults/.

Comment: That path above should be:  /etc/default/tomcat7  (note the lack of 's' in default)

Comment: I had to take the additional steps outlined in Rose's answer as well to get this to work on ubuntu

Comment: What is the equal for Tomcat 9 ?

Comment: @katu It's the same, but the line does not exists, commented or not, you have to add it.

Answer (score 29):

On Ubuntu and Debian systems, there are several steps needed:

1. In server.xml, change the line `<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>` to have `port="80"`.
2. Install the recommended (not required) authbind package, with a command like:

   `sudo apt-get install authbind`
3. Enable authbind in the server.xml file (in either `/etc/tomcat6` or `/etc/tomcat7`) by uncommenting and setting the line like:

   `AUTHBIND=yes`

All three steps are needed.

Comment: Doesn't work for Tomcat (if installed by zip/tar.gz) in 13.10.

Comment: To get it to work from zip/tar.gz, do steps 1 and 2 above, add AUTHBIND=yes to bin/setenv.sh (create if not there) and start from root. Works with LTS 12.04, should also work w/13.10.

Comment: In my case it failed (with no error message in catalina.out) without the authbind package, worked after installing it

Comment: Could you please point to the documentation about AUTHBIND=yes? I find it nowhere.

Comment: I cannot find a mention of the AUTHBIND setting as part of the server element configuration in the TOMCAT documentation either. Strange.

Comment: Why do you say `authbind` is recommended?

Comment: The authbind package was a recommended, rather than required, package in Ubuntu at the time. It is needed for the server.xml configuration to work. You can check if it is installed with 'pkg -s authbind'

Answer (score 23):

I tried changing the port from `8080` to `80` in the `server.xml` but it didn't work for me. Then I found alternative, update the `iptables` which i'm sure there is an impact on performance.

I use the following commands:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo /sbin/service iptables save
```

http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-advanced.html#port80

Comment: how to revert this?

Comment: Run the following command to remove the routing: iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

Answer (score 19):

As previous answers didn't work well (it was good, but not enough) for me on a 14.04 Ubuntu Server, I mention [these recommendations](http://www.2ality.com/2010/07/running-tomcat-on-port-80-in-user.html) (this is a quote).

Edit: note that as @jason-faust mentioned it in the comments, *on 14.04, the `authbind` package that ships with it does support IPv6 now, so the prefer IPv4 thing isn't needed any longer*.

```
1) Install authbind
2) Make port 80 available to authbind (you need to be root):

  touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
  chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
  chown tomcat7 /etc/authbind/byport/80

3) Make IPv4 the default (authbind does not currently support IPv6).
   To do so, create the file TOMCAT/bin/setenv.sh with the following content: 

   CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

4) Change /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh

  exec authbind --deep "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
  # OLD: exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
```

If you already got a `setenv.sh` file  in `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin` with `CATALINA_OPTS`, you have to use :

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Now you can change the port to `80` as told in other answers.

Comment: I would add that the startup.sh file is located at: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh - Its not completely obvious to us newbies ;)

Comment: @ConMan updated paths, that's a great idea to save other searchs. I admit that knowing this place is not obvious in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great, I'm used to centos, so this was helpful to me, where this was not an issue for me.

Comment: I just followed this today on 14.04, the authbind package that ships with it does support IPv6 now, so the prefer IPv4 thing isn't needed any longer.

Comment: I also did: chmod 755 /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh

Answer (score 5):

On modern linux the best approach (for me) is to use xinetd :

1) create /etc/xinet.d/tomcat-http

```
service http
{
        disable = no
        socket_type = stream
        user = root
        wait = no
        redirect = 127.0.0.1 8080
}
```

2) create /etc/xinet.d/tomcat-https

```
service https
{
        disable = no
        socket_type = stream
        user = root
        wait = no
        redirect = 127.0.0.1 8443
}
```

3) chkconfig xinetd on

4) /etc/init.d/xinetd start

Comment: Other approach is to compile and use jsvc but xinetd is definitely easier

Answer (score 5):

If someone is looking for, how to change the tomcat port number in Eclipse IDE user following are the steps.

1.In the Servers view, double click on the server name:
[image]

2.That will open a configuration page for Tomcat as follows:
[image]

3.Notice the port numbers are shown in the table on the right. Click to edit, for example:
[image]

4.That will change port number for HTTP from 8080 to 80. Press Ctrl + S to save the change and restart the server. We can spot the change of port number in the Console view:
[image]

This all content were taken from below link, please refer that link for further information thanks.
http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-change-port-numbers-for-tomcat-in-eclipse

Answer (score 4):

Running the command below worked with. Tried changing `server.xml` and the conf file but both didn't work.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Answer (score 3):

On a linux server you can just use this commands to reconfigure Tomcat to listen on port 80:

```
sed -i 's|port="8080"|port="80"|g' /etc/tomcat?/server.xml
sed -i 's|#AUTHBIND=no|AUTHBIND=yes|g' /etc/default/tomcat?
service tomcat8 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using eclipse and modifying server.xml doesn't work for you then try following [article](http://www.iiftl.com/post/8).. they have steps to modify port if you are using IDE like eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Just goto conf folder of tomcat

open the server.xml file

Goto one of the connector node which look like the following

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Simply change the port

save and restart tomcat

Comment: On Windows only isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

--> Follow the path: {tomcat directory>/conf
-->Find this line:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

change portnumber from "8080" to "80".

--> Save the file.

--> Restart the server 
:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to edit the file. Open file `/etc/default/tomcat7` and change

```
#AUTHBIND=no
```

to

```
AUTHBIND=yes
```

then restart.

Comment: Or create it if it doesn't exist