# Deploying a web service and a web service client on different ports in localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I have web service which i built using apache axis2 and java w/ eclipse. I have also implemented a web service client. I ran the client as a java app in eclipse and it works perfectly with the web service. But now i want to run it as a web-based client. When i deployed, it is trying to use the default port(8080) of tomcat. But that port is already in use by the web service. So how do I run deploy my client on a different port from eclipse.

Comment: A client has nothing to do with tomcat, or its port.

Comment: what servlet container do you use?

Comment: I'm using Apache Tomcat 6.

Comment: what you client application should do?

Comment: If you are asking what my client app does. It sends a numeric value to the service and gets a return value based on some calculation. The output works fine when I run on eclipse IDE as a java application. When i try to run on server. It get an exception `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind` and `404` error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the port of tomcat from 8080 to 80?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)

Answer (score 0):

you hosted the service and client in two different tomcat instances which are running in port 8080? change one instance's port ..