# access web application with domain name

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, dns

I have my web application deployed in tomcat. Right now its accessed using the IP in the URL.

> **`http://IPaddress:8080/appname/index.html`**

I wanted to configure a domain name in the DNS server which maps to this IP name. My windows admin created a domain. But problem is I'm not able to use it directly. Its expecting the port number.

> **`http://domain.com:8080/appname/index.html`**

My expectation :

> **`http://domain.com --> http://IP:8080/appname/index.html`**

How do I configure so that my tomcat recognizes the domain name with out the port number.

Comment: You can't do this with just DNS.  You would need a proxy or a redirector to do this; *something* has to be listening on port 80 for HTTP to "just work" without a port number, either you or something fronting your application.

Comment: @satish jonnala i want to do the same have you got any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You have to change port from `8080`, to `80`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758356/841176 for instructions.

Comment: I tried doing that. I followed the instructions and changed to http listening on 80. But, this is resulting in Object not found! page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to do a port forwarding on the router. Tell your admin that any requests coming to domain.com (IP) should be redirected to IP:8080 instead of IP:80

Answer (score 0):

It's common to run Apache in front of Tomcat which could forward incoming port 80 requests to port 8080. You'd need to enable the `mod_proxy` module in Apache and then you can configure Apache to forward the requests - something like this:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyPass         /appname  http://IPAddress:8080/appname
ProxyPassReverse  /appname  http://IPAddress:8080/appname
```

Then requests to `http://domain.com/appname` will be forwarded to `http://IPAddress:8080/appname`.

See [the mod_proxy docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for more info.