# www.abc.org:8080/xyz.jsp is working when i submit a form data

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

`www.abc.org:8080/xyz.jsp` is working, when i submit a form data . it will redirect a page to `www.abc.org:8080/xyz.jsp?msg=Mail%20has%20been%20sent` works.  But when i hit  url  `www.abc.org/xyz.jsp` ,and  submit a form data, form is not working. It shows 404 error and `www.abc.org/firstservlet`. is there any configuration in `server.xml` file for port related.
My server  `Tomcat7.`please help any one.

Comment: You can find it pretty easily : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80

Comment: my hosting plan is shared,so  port can't be change.

Comment: If this is an hosting plan, you will probably be better ask them how to do it. If they can't... I don't think this is a good one!

Comment: just now i called him and they told apache is bind with tomcat so they cann't change port.if they change then collide occurs. there is another option, authbind uncomment this.i told him they check.

Comment: what is the exact solution of this problem?Anyone ... help me.