# why do I need port 8080 after localhost?

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

I've just downloaded a java application called "test-app" that I obtained from http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html and I setup tomcat 7 in eclipse.
When I started the server I navigated to `http://localhost/test-app` and got a page could not be found error, but when I went to `http://localhost:8080/test-app/` the page came up correctly.
Why is this occurring? The tutorial I'm following states that I should be able to navigate to the page without the 8080.

Comment: Here is the solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe port 8080 is the default port for tomcat installations. There should be a file called `conf/server.xml` which you can change it from `8080` to `80`.

Look in server.xml for this line:

```
 <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

And change `Connector port="8080"` to `Connector port="80"`

Comment: Just remember that port 80 need admin privileges, that is why 8080 is default

Comment: I found the server.xml file, but I eventually modified it through eclipse, by right-clicking on the server, open, and changed 'HTTP' to from 8080 to 80. I was able to navigate to `http://localhost/test-app`. The odd thing is that I changed it back to 8080, back to 80, and back to 8080 again, and I was able to open the test-app at `http://localhost/test-app` with the port set to 8080.

Comment: Odd. I'm not a fan of tomcat, but stumbled on this issue when I had to set up a server with it. Glad it worked for you!