# tomcat7 unable to listen on port 80

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to get tomcat7 to listen on port 80 instead of 8080 on ubuntu 12.  I changed the server.xml file to point to port 80 instead of port 8080 - when I restart tomcat, the service does not appear to run at all.  No other service is currently binding onto port 80.
Any thoughts on troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="443" />
```

Comment: Try to start the service as root. Does it work?

Comment: Have you checked, that port 80 is not in use by another (http) server?

Comment: yes, port 80 is open and I am running this as root.

Comment: Is there any chance the URL you are using specifies HTTPS scheme (either with or without port 80 explicitly .. for example, `https://host:80`)? The connector would try to redirect to 443.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is already answered.  You can't just set tomcat to listen on 80, you have to adjust iptables (there are other approaches)

[How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)

Comment: will try changing AUTHBIND to 'yes' and revert (AUTHBIND in /etc/defaults/tomcat7 on ubuntu12)