# While connecting tomcatv 7.0.54 with Eclipse Luno, How to clear port collision error?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I am using windows 8 os. While connecting Tomcat with Eclipse , I have encountered the following error.

```
    Several ports (90, 80) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use.       
    The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using  
    the   port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the  
    port number(s).
```

I have tried all the Recovery methods given in the previous answers. But, Still now I cant clear the error. Kindly guide me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the case that there are multiple instances if the same tomcat running. So you can also try restarting eclipse. And also you can terminate all of the java process from the task manager.
At last you can try changing the ports of the tomcat, from the server.xml file.

[How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)

Comment: my server has started successfully...... But, when running the program, Same error occurs.

Comment: Program?? What sort of program?

Comment: I need to run a simple JSP program. While running that, same error is repeating

Comment: It seems that you are starting the server and then, you are right clicking on the project and clicking on run on server?..
In that case you have to stop the server and then right click on the project and click on run on server. This will start the server and run your app.

Comment: yes .......... I got it..... But, the following is the result..
HTTP Status 404 - /k1/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /k1/

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.54