# Tomcat7 won't start up on ubuntu (clean install), permission denied

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat7, port

I have a clean ubuntu installation (14) and try to run Tomcat7. I have installed it via terminal, run the "sudo service tomcat7 start" command which should start tomcat, but when I try to open: localhost:8080, the welcome index page is not loading and I get a 404 error (file not found). The 8080 port is not opened either, it seem like some kind of permission problem.

---

Netstat gives the following (note there is not listening for 8080 with tomcat started)

```
android@localhost:~$ netstat -a | more
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:5900                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.102:5900     94.102.51.229:26238     SYN_RECV   
tcp        0      0 *:x11                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.102:ssh      192.168.10.106:51076    ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       1      0 192.168.10.102:37029    bud02s01-in-f9.1e1:http CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6       0      0 192.168.10.102:33087    ea-in-f188.1e100.n:5228 ESTABLISHED
udp6       0      0 [::]:56456              [::]:*                             
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2049     /dev/socket/vold
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2062     /dev/socket/displayd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2064     /dev/socket/mdns
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2066     /dev/socket/dnsproxyd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2068     /dev/socket/netd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2462     /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_c
trl_347-1
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2463     /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_c
trl_347-2
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2070     /dev/socket/rild-debug
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     109645   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_sock
et
unix  4      [ ]         DGRAM                    2496     /data/misc/wifi/sockets/p2p0
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    3401     /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wpa_c
trl_347-3
```

Catalina.out (log), gives the following error:

```
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:308)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:397)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

Sep 08, 2014 9:52:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:308)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:397)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more

Sep 08, 2014 9:52:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 4826 ms
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Sep 08, 2014 9:52:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Sep 08, 2014 9:53:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 24972 ms
Sep 08, 2014 9:53:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:308)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

Sep 08, 2014 9:53:17 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 08, 2014 9:53:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 08, 2014 9:53:17 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 08, 2014 9:53:17 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

---

Solved:

The 8080 port was not in use, I even tried to change it to 8089 to be sure. There was something other, anyway.
I have removed all tomcat7 via command line, and reinstalled manually. After installing the latest version from the Apache website everything was ok.

Step by step guide can be found [here.](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-tomcat-7-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: Have you already tried finding the `startup.sh` of your Tomcat and do you get any errors when starting Tomcat using the shell script?

Comment: Try the command "netstat -tuplen" and see the list of ports in use along with process IDs. See which PID is bound with 8080

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have another service running on port 8080, or your kernel somehow has that port closed. Try configuring another port and see if the problem persists.

Edit: Ok, here comes the actionable part: open a terminal and run

```
netstat -t | grep 8080
```

This should show you anything currently listening on port 8080. As Ubuntu doesn't activate a firewall out of the box, this is very likely the source of the problem.

Another edit: The original question did not state that you were on Android. This is a vital piece of information, as Android includes SELinux, which forbids opening a port without prior consent from the security layer. To allow opening the port, look [here](http://amorbatayola.com/blog/79-howto/79-disabling-opening-additional-ports-in-selinux).

Comment: That should be a comment

Comment: @llogiq, "netstat -t | grep 8080"- gives no result. After that I have changed the port to 8077, and restarted tomcat but I get the exact same error. I am connected to the system via VNC, and I have deployed ubuntu on a Android system. In turn yesterday befeore cleaning the installation I had no problem running Apache2.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester, you may be right. I added a simple command to find out if that is indeed the source of the problem. Is it now an answer or should I delete it and re-post as a comment?

Comment: @llogiq Lets wait and see what the OP says

Comment: @llogiq - Interesting suggestion. SELinux might well be the culprit.  Look here for more details on troubleshooting, and a possible fix: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/practical-selinux-port-contexts-and-handling-access-alerts/.

Answer (score 0):

Here you just have to change the port number from the tomcat manager because some applications may already using the port you given as 8080.

Use the following method...

[How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)