# Tomcat 7 - Ubuntu : create a domain name instead of IP:8080/appName

Tags: tomcat7

I have deployed my webapp on an Ubuntu server in my company.
the war is in the folder :

> /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

Tomcat7 has deployed the archive in the folder

> /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bioApp/

My problem is that to access the web app I need to type the url :

> http://IP_OF_SERVER:8080/bioApp

I would like the users to type :

> www.bioApp.com

I have tried many solutions (modifying server.xml, hosts file, etc).
None of them work.
If anyone has a working solution...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is a local dns server in your company. In your dns server add a rule to route your ip (IP_OF_SERVER) to the local domain name

```
 IP_OF_SERVER bioApp.com
```

If you had an apache server, you must add a virtualhost in your conf file (See [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for more information)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bioApp.com
  ProxyPass / http://IP_OF_SERVER:8080/bioApp
  ProxyPassReverse / http://IP_OF_SERVER:8080/bioAppr

</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't have a apache server, you can change your tomcat listen port.(See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)).