# How to handle java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] exception

Tags: java, windows, sockets, tomcat, tomcat7

I needed to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80 so that I can execute my web app as `http://localhost`. I followed already answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)  of stackoverflow.

As I started tomcat 7, it generates the following Exception:

> SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-80"]
>   java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

This is the problem. How to handle this exception in tomcat 7 in windows 7?

Comment: Is Windows firewall configured to allow inbound traffic to port 80?  Seems to me I remember that it blocks that port by default.

Comment: Yes, Windows firewall is configured to allow inbound traffic to port 80. I had already created that rule.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the port 80 is already used by some other service.
If you want to run your app in port 80 then shutdown already port 80 service and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Ports < 1024 usually require greater (admin) privileges; I am betting you're running as a normal/limited user.

Comment: No, I'm not running as a normal user,but I'm running as administrator of `Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard`