# Setup host domain for spring for API and angular content as main domain

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

How do I setup my Spring application to use hosts / domains correctly?

I am fairly new to Spring so hopefully I am describing my setup adequately to you.

My Spring setup has Tomcat built in via the configuration file `WEB-INF/web.xml` and `WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and it autogenerates / listens on `localhost:8080/spring-ng-seed` (the name of the project for now).

If I put into my `/etc/host` file:

```
127.0.0.1 spring-ng-seed.dev
127.0.0.1 api.spring-ng-seed.dev
```

then I still have to type into my browser `spring-ng-seed.dev:8080/spring-ng-seed/index.html`

How can I loose the port number and the app name prefix before index.html? (`:8080/spring-ng-seed`)

Also, is it possible to have my API only respond on `api.spring-ng-seed.dev` and not on `spring-ng-seed.dev` ? i.e have:

1) `spring-ng-seed.dev` only serve the NG app

2) `api.spring-ng-seed.dev` only serve the API

My `WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    "
>

    <context:component-scan base-package="seed.rest.api"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/app/build/"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:protect-pointcut expression="execution(* seed.rest.api.*.*.**(..))"
                                   access="ROLE_DUMMY"/>
    </security:global-method-security>

</beans>
```

My `WEB-INF/web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd
    "
    version="3.0"
>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

If there is any other configurations that you need from my project ill happily post them.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To skip typing in the port into the browser you can change tomcat to run on port 80 (see [How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80))

To map apps to subdomains consider using apache (which can also perform the first part of your question. see http://squirrel.pl/blog/2010/03/30/mapping-tomcat-apps-to-subdomains-with-apache/)

Comment: I don't have a `server.xml` file. My tomcat is in the project from my `pom.xml` and configured in `web.xml`

From what I can see, this is for if we have tomcat installed on the system instead of being embedded into the project like I have. If I paste the `<Connector ...> ` in my `web.xml` or `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` it does nothing.