# How to map java web application to domain name in Linux server

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat7

I placed the my java web application in tomcat7 webapps folder in linux server.

My application is running with port number 8080, my app url is `http://xxxx:8080/xxxx/#/`

How can I map the application to domain name `http://xxxx.in`?

Comment: when launch the domain getting the following page
url:https://s31.postimg.org/kwd7nb9d7/ilovesales.png

Answer (score 1):

The answers below should be all you need:
[How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)
[Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

Before you do any of the above you should stop Apache HTTPD (not Apache Tomcat) as it is already running on port 80 (and you don't really need it).

Comment: how to stop Apache HTTPD?

Answer (score 0):

Check inside your /etc/rc.d/init.d/ directory for services available and use command stop (servicename) to stop it