# how to use port 8080 instead of port 80 when IP address entered

Tags: jsp, ip, port

I have a domain name and I have connected a domain name to my IP address but when I enter a domain name, by default port 80 is used and to see the jsp page. I have to write domain-name:8080. So how do I make 8080 port a default port so that when domain name is entered it directly goes to port 8080.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to write a jsp page that will redirect to an address on port 8080? The browsers control what port is used for http by default.

Comment: You could rather change a listening port of your servlet container (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)) from 8080 to 80. Otherwise, an answer will depend on the environment you use.

Comment: Yes just change the server to listen on port 80.

Comment: @takendarkk how to change server to listen on port 80

Comment: What server are you running?