# How do I use different port for different application running on the same tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

My `8080` port is used by Jenkins. I want to deploy one more application which uses TomCat but I want a different port. Can some one help me on this?

Comment: Did you even attempt to research this before you posted your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80)