# Tomcat on Linux server is not running on port 80

Tags: linux, port, tomcat6

I have application running on tomcat server which is in Linux environment. When I'm running my application on Browser I give the URL as http://xxxx.xxx.com/Home/Login.jsp it does not work. Only by adding 8080 in the URL works. which is http://xxxx.xxx.com:8080/Home/Login.jsp.

Is there any way to resolve this issue and make it work without 8080 port number?

Comment: look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesn't work. May be because my tomcat is running on Linux server

Comment: Are you sure that your linux server is listening HTTP protocol in port 80 ?

Comment: I'm not sure of that. IS there any configuration needs to be done in my linux server to make it listen to port 80

Comment: port 80 is the default value, but try something like that : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Security_Guide/s1-server-ports.html

Comment: Looks like Linux server is not listening to port 80.

$ netstat -an | grep 80| grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN  


Only 8005 & 8009 port are in use. Is there any way To make Linux server listen to 80

Answer (score 0):

You can run tomcat code through IIS. By using IIS you can avoid using 8080 port number.
Ref: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-iis-howto.html