# Why <myWebsite.com>:8080 works while <mywebsite.com> doesn't work for tomcat server running on Ec2?

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have my webapp running on Tomcat which is running on an EC2 instance. 
I have set up my instance's inbound rules properly.

When I enter `<myWebsite.com>:8080` it works from my browser. 
For `<myWebsite.com>` it does not load. Rather I get the following error message:

```
This site can’t be reached <myWebsite.com> refused to connect.
Search Google for <my Website> home
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Maybe your tomcat does not listen on TCP port 80?

Answer (score 2):

When you try to connect directly via `myWebsite.com`, your browser will default to http on port 80. Apparently, your webserver is listening on port 8080 though.

You need to configure Tomcat to listen for incoming requests on port 80.

There are many tutorials and questions here on stackoverflow about how to change the tomcat port from 8080 to 80.

E.g from [How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80):

> 1) Go to `conf` folder in tomcat installation directory
>
> ```
> e.g. C:\Tomcat 6.0\conf\
> ```
>
> 2) Edit following tag in `server.xml` *file*
>
> 3) Change the `port=8080` value to `port=80`
>
> 4) Save file.
>
> 5) Stop your Tomcat and restart it.

Keep in mind that, by default, Tomcat will not start on port 80, unless run as root. However, running as root is generally considered bad practice.
The following resource summarizes well how to mitigate this problem with Tomcat and EC2:
https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-advanced.html#port80

The easiest solution would be to redirect the tomcat port (e.g.8080) via iptables:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo /sbin/service iptables save
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. Tried Authbind as well. Doesn't work.

Comment: After doing as you said In catalina.out, 
`13-Mar-2019 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-80"]
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`

Comment: Good answer(+1). As per the new comment it is an amazon-ec2 or more generally unix specific issue. The solutions is here: [ec2 and tomcat7: can't connect on port 80](https://serverfault.com/questions/317679/ec2-and-tomcat7-cant-connect-on-port-80#317683) @sofs1

Comment: Thank you! I added information about how to mitigate port 80 permission problems. In general, I think my answer was correct. The problem is that you need to have your Tomcat listen on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After following several answers in StackOverflow, following worked

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo /sbin/iptables-save
```

Following didn't work

1. Assigning Elastic Ip for VPC and using it to connect to the
   instance.
2. Changing tomcat server.xml port from 8080 to 80.

Note: My Ec2 instance's security group's inbound rules were accepting `HTTP` at port `80` from anywhere.

Comment: I think it should be noted that configuring tomcat to run on port 80 is a viable alternative. However, only if run as root or configured in conjunction with authbind.