# Hide port in apex oracle address (Apache Tomcat 9 )

Tags: oracle, tomcat, oracle-apex

I turned apex oracle to linux, my link looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/ords/
```

I want the link to look like this:

```
http://localhost/ords/
```

I have tried to change the ttomcat settings: [How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80), like here, but it didn't help, I'll dragging his forehead help)!

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't help" is there an error? or what exactly doesn't work

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: @sc0der Centos7

Comment: You can use firewalld to forward the port

Comment: @micklesh I did everything as there, changed the port to 80 from 8080, and made a restart, there were no errors, but just when I go to http: // localhost tells me that the server is not available, although it was not enough to go to Tomсat

Comment: @sc0der and you can get more details on how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

You do this in different methods, the simplest one using the `firewalld`

1. Add port firwalld from 80 to 8080 permanent
2. Reload the firwalld

`firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080 --permanent`

`firewall-cmd --reload`

More information: [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-port_forwarding)