# Trying to mask tomcat address with 8080 port with domain address

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache, tomcat

I want to have an intranet site such that
There is a machine with static IP address: 192.168.88.80
Mapped via hosts file to domain: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
Then I want to map an address such that when I enter the following in browser address bar: http://app.example.com
It loads my Tomcat hosted application at http://www.example.com:8080/app but address bar still displays http://app.example.com
I have tried several combinations but not able to configure such. I keep getting http://www.example.com:8080/app in my browser bar.
Does anyone have any idea, preferably using Apache httpd
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using apache httpd and tomcat by using the reverseProxy settings

1. Uncomment the appropriate line in Apache’s httpd.conf file to enable the Apache mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http modules

   LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

   LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
2. add an Apache proxypass and an Apache proxypassreverse entry at the end of the httpd.conf file.

   ProxyPass /sample http://localhost:8080/sample

   ProxyPassReverse /sample http://localhost:8080/sample

See https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-configure-Apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-example for more details

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to address this, without any extra software is, is to [run Tomcat on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80), which will fix the 8080 part, and to rename your war file to ROOT.war, which address the context part (the `app` in the URL).